# Which collection to use for fixed list of values

Tags: c#, collections

I have data as below which I want to populate in a `collection` depending on the direction of the angle. I want the collection to have the sum value of the quantity. Which collection should I use?

```
double angle = 20;
double quantity = 200;

double angle = 20;
double quantity = 250;

double angle = 30;
double quantity = 300;

double angle = 40;
double quantity = 400;
```

Till now I have attempted to create a `dictionary` with an enum as below. I am sure sure if this is a good idea. Is there a bettwer way

```
public enum Direction
{
    NorthToNortheast,
    NortheastToEast,
    EastToSoutheast,
    SoutheastToSouth,
    SouthToSouthwest,
    SouthwestToWest,
    WestToNorthwest,
    NorthwestToNorth
}
```

In my class

```
Dictionary<Direction, double> elements = new Dictionary<Direction, double>();
```

Then for each value I am populating the dictionary

```
if (angle >= 0 && angle < 45)
    elements[Direction.NorthToNortheast] += quantity;
else if (angle >= 45 && angle < 90)
    elements[Direction.NortheastToEast] += quantity;
```

Comment: try using mod as if your angle can be greater than 360 also

Comment: No my angle is never more than 360

Comment: Are you sure you need a collection? You could also create a class with properties for each of the directions.

Comment: Which collection also depends on how you want to do with the collection, not only depends on the data

Comment: what is the problem you are having, exactly? why is this dictionary approach not good enough? btw. maybe you could simplify your `if`s and use `(int)(angle / 45)` as a key

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't simple use a few sum variables, and then loop through whichever array contains your information? This is because you know the fixed number of sums you will need (e.g. one for every 45 degrees) E.g. `var sum1, sum2, ... = 0; foreach (var i in info) { if (info.angle >= 0 && info.angle < 45) sum1 += info.quantity; else if (info.angle >= 45 && info.angle < 90) sum2 += info.quantity; else if....`.

Comment: @slawekwin I am not having any problems. I just wanted to know if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: @Keyur That is what I am currently doing.

Comment: but you have not given us enough context to know what you are doing exactly, so we don't know what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @slawekwin or if his angle breaks are fixed, he could use (int)(angle % 45) also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify the direction lookup by keeping the directions and angles in a list, something like:

```
static readonly IReadOnlyList<CardinalDirection> _directionsByAngle = InitDirections();

// map each starting angle to a direction,
// sorted descending (largest angle first)
static IReadOnlyList<CardinalDirection> InitDirections()
{
    return new List<CardinalDirection>
    {
        new CardinalDirection (0, Direction.NorthToNortheast),
        new CardinalDirection (45, Direction.NortheastToEast),
        ...
    }
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.StartAngle)
    .ToList();
}

// find the first (largest) d.StartAngle such that angle >= d.StartAngle
static CardinalDirection GetDirectionForAngle(double angle)
{
    return _directionsByAngle
        .Where(d => angle >= d.StartAngle)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Depending on what you want to do with the value, keeping the total in the dictionary like you are using now would work fine. With the snipped above, you would have:

```
var direction = GetDirectionForAngle(angle % 360);
elements[direction.Direction] += quantity;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use each enum values as a Property in a collector class:

```
//The class is describing your items
class Item
    {
        public double Angle;
        public double Quantity;

        public Item(double angle, double quantity)
        {
            Angle = angle;
            Quantity = quantity;
        }       
    }

//Collector class
class Element
{
    public Element()
    {
        NorthToNortheast.Quantity = 200;
        NorthToNortheast.Angle = 250;

        NortheastToEast.Quantity = 30;
        NortheastToEast.Angle = 300;
    }
    public Item NorthToNortheast { set; get; }
    public Item NortheastToEast { set; get; }
}
```